# Why is X staying = 1?

Tags: python, time, pyautogui, integer-arithmetic

```
while 1:

    x=+1
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    pic.save(str(x)+".png", "PNG")
    print(x)
    time.sleep(5)
```

X won't increase every time the loop, loops

I want the screenshot to save under a different name every time it screenshots, so I put x=+1 to constantly give a new name for the screen shot to save under but it only stays at one.

Comment: `x=+1` means "x equals positive one".  You have swapped the `=` and `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You should write `x += 1` which means `x = x + 1`.

Here you just value the `x` to `+1` (`x = +1`)

**A little advice:** *is better to write mathematical syntax with space to don't get problems like this.*

Comment: Adding spaces wouldn't help in this case.  `x =+ 1` is equivalent t- `x = + 1`, i.e. `x = (+ 1)`.  The spaces improve readability, but they wouldn't have prevented this, which seems like more of a dyslexia issue.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I didn't say to solve this problem with space. I said that you can prevent such problems.
Here, if he had worked with space from the beginning, he would have noticed the problem in his code more easily.